# How to set light paths with drivers based on if the user is rendering

Tags: python, drivers

I am setting up a project where while in the viewport, glossy light paths must be set to 0. But when the user renders I need to set glossy paths to 1. I have no experience with blender python or drivers in general but if Im not mistaken this should be possible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a task for drivers and is probably best done with [Application Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html).  I would do this by registering handlers for [render.pre](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_pre) and [render.post](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_post).  The pre handler would set glossy paths to 1 and the post to 0, of course.

To be extra careful you might want to add an additional function that blender calls at startup to ensure that glossy paths is set to 0 initially. Do be aware of the warning about persistent handlers at the start of the manual section on Application Handlers.

This all assumes this is meant for Cycles.

Comment: Ahh alright thanks so much

Comment: @ben you're welcome.  Good luck with your setup.